# How can I use data from the workspace in an equation?

Tags: matlab

I have two tables of data in the workspace on Matlab, and I want to use an equation that takes the first value from each table, does the calculation, then the 2nd value from each and so on... and stores these output numbers.

I could probably do this if I was just defining the data arrays myself in the code, but I'm stuck when trying to do it from the workspace...

Comment: Its the same as defining it in the code. The workspace is equivalent with prior defined variables. So in your code you do "A=..." then later "B=A*...". If A is saved in the workspace you just have to do the second comand. If you are looking for elementwise operations check out the help section for `bsxfun()`

Comment: See: [scripts vs. functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html). Functions operate in their own [workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html), scripts operate in the base MATLAB workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Is it inside a function? You could pass the workspace variables as arguments to the function, or use `evalin('base', 'variableName')` to get the values (this second method is HIGHLY discouraged however).